# spring-boot-2, Serving plain old jsp pages WITHOUT controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, war

I'm trying to convert an old legacy application from JavaEE to spring-boot-2.

How do you actually serve plain old JSP-pages WITHOUT a Controller?

I've been googling this over and over now, and strange as it sounds, I cannot figure it out or find a simple example that actually WORKS. I just keep getting "404 Not Found" when trying to access the JSP.

I'm using maven, packaging as a WAR file and I'm fine running it as 'exploded' (which seems the best bet?), still haven't been able to make it work.

I don't understand how this can be so hard, is it no longer POSSIBLE to do this in spring-boot-2?

Anyone can **point me to a working example?**
Or a **detailed instruction** how to?

**EDIT**: This is what spring docs say re. JSP Limitations:

"With Jetty and Tomcat, it **should work** if you use war packaging."
From: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/

But exactly **how**? That's what I'm trying to figure out...

Comment: In WAR where do you have the JSP files.

Comment: I've actually tried 'everything' I could find, but none that worked so far. Where do you recommend?

Comment: JSP pages are compiled to servlets by the servlet engine, so do you want Spring to serve you JSP views from its Controllers, or do you want to bypass Spring completely and use JSPs in the traditional way (which you seem to be asking, and which isn't related to Spring at all)?

Comment: @Kayaman -- if the code works in JavaEE container (or plain old Tomcat), but not when I deploy the same to Spring-Boot, I think the issue has some relationship to Spring, doesn't it? --- see the correct answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Spring Boot by default takes over the world, i.e. it registers the `DispatcherServlet` with a servlet mapping of `/`, thereby high-jacking the servlet containers processing of `*.jsp` files.

To allow the servlet container to process JSPs normally, we need to make sure the Spring `DispatcherServlet` doesn't intercept them, e.g. by ensuring that it only handles requests with certain suffixes, or with certain prefixes.

E.g. if no JSP path starts with `/api/`, then we can use that for the `DispatcherServlet`, i.e. any request for `/api/*` will be handled by Spring Boot, and any other request will be handled by the servlet container.

To do that, add the following to the `application.properties` file:

```
spring.mvc.servlet.path = /api
```

Comment: BINGO!!  Yes, FINALLY! THAT solved it!! THANK YOU Andreas, where can I send you a Beer?!! :)

Comment: 'Spring Boot by default takes over the world' -- Good line, btw. That's true in more than one way! :)

Answer (score -1):

have you declared the servlet mapping somewhere?
i believe u need a point of entry otherwise is just a dead file pointing to nowhere

Comment: Servlet mappings are for servlets, afaik. ---   Plain old JSP pages, I would at maximum expect a config-parameter pointing to their location, or something.

Comment: sorry my explanation failed, I meant that in a Spring Environment you need to set that up. I do not see my answer as fully wrong, just incomplete